# Sum of two rows case when

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as :

```
Store    SALES   
A1       200 
A2       100
B1       400
```

Case when `store` = `A1` or `A2`, i want to add sum of those 2 rows in one row, as follows :

```
Store    SALES
A1       300
B1       400
```

I have tried sum case when, but not sure how to use it in my case

Comment: what code have you tried so far? does this only need to be for A1 & A2 or will the final list be much longer? if it is longer will store names always be 1 letter and 1 number?

Comment: If B2 is available then what will be the result?

Comment: bad logic, you need rethink solution, trouble not here, trouble in business logic. This is crutch.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate using a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Store IN ('A1', 'A2') THEN 'A1' ELSE Store END AS Store,
    SUM(SALES) AS SALES
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Store IN ('A1', 'A2') THEN 'A1' ELSE Store END;
```